# How to build a Cosine Similarity function in R?

Tags: r, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity

This is my action_slippers Datalist. Please note that this just the part of it:

```
                    X_id                       cd      iios                       ui     w
1  56548c6ab65dd425cc3dda13 2015-11-24T16:12:26.572Z 194635691 563734c3b65dd40e340eaa56 0.010
2  56548df4b84c321fe4cdfb91 2015-11-24T16:19:00.798Z 194153563 56548df4b84c321fe4cdfb8f 0.010
3  56548fc7735e782a88591662 2015-11-24T16:26:46.952Z 177382028 563e12657d4c410c5832579c 0.010
4  565494e1b84c321fe4ce2f44 2015-11-24T16:48:33.828Z 177382031 563e12657d4c410c5832579c 0.010
5  5654994a735e782a88595802 2015-11-24T17:07:18.269Z 195129144 56549946735e782a885957e6 0.080
6  56549ce2b65dd425cc3e550c 2015-11-24T17:22:42.775Z 196972549 565181854c24b410e4891e11 0.010
7  56549f9bb84c321fe4ce7a3a 2015-11-24T17:34:19.732Z 194153563 56549f9bb84c321fe4ce7a37 0.010
8  5654a35a735e782a8859a055 2015-11-24T17:50:18.068Z 196258704 5654a35a735e782a8859a053 0.010
9  5654a5bab8e3a9227cffd593 2015-11-24T18:00:26.102Z 194907960 56320e0e55e89c3e14e26d3d 0.010
10 5654a7bb735e782a8859c495 2015-11-24T18:08:59.476Z 196950156 5651b53fec231f1df8482d23 0.027
```

iios    :Unique id for the item. This is the field for relating items in these files to items files.

ui  :   Unique id for the user.

w   :   0.01 means the user looked at the item. 0.08 means the user added the item to cart, 0.027 means a purchase.

What I want to do with this data list is build a function when purchased happened(w=0.027) that should order top 8 user which most similar to based on user who purchased a item with using cosine similarity formula(w=0.027)

I have tried these codes so far but ı could not get the vector of user who purchase for compare with the other users:

```
user_sim=function(i,actions_slippers){

for (i in 1:nrow(actions_slippers)) {

if (actions_slippers$w[i]==0.027) {


  for (j in 1:i) {
    user_id=actions_slippers$ui[i]
    mydf <- data.frame(
      ui = c(actions_slippers$ui[1:i]),
      w = c(actions_slippers$w[1:i]),
      iios = factor(
        c(actions_slippers$iios[1:i]),
        levels = unique(x)))

  action=  dcast(mydf, formula = ui ~ iios, 
          fill = 0, value.var = "w", 
          fun.aggregate = sum, drop = FALSE)


  p=as.vector(cosine(t(a[,2:ncol(a)]))[,1])
  t=a[,-1]
  u_sim=t*p
  col_sum=colSums(u_sim)
  t_sum=colSums(t)
  res1=col_sum/t_sum
  newdata1=data.frame(res1)
  max1 <- newdata1[order(res1[1:8],decreasing=TRUE),]




  }

}
}    
}
```

I used `reshape2` package to get action dataframe that looks like below. My problem is I cant get the user vector who purchased and then need to calculate cosine similarity with each user between who purchased item.

Here in my code I calculate cosine similarity based on first row of actions data frame at below between each other rows but as I mention above I need to get vector of purchased user and calculate cosine similarity based on this vector between each other user

```
  ui 194635691 194153563 177382028 177382031 195129144 196972549 196258704 194907960 196950156 194139014 153444738 192982501 192891196
1 237      0.01      0.01      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.01     0.000         0         0         0         0
2 261      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0         0         0
3 290      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0         0         0
4 483      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0         0         0
5 485      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.027         0         0         0         0
6 533      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0         0         0
7 534      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0         0         0
8 535      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0         0         0
9 536      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.00     0.000         0         0         0         0
```

Can anyone tell me What should I do?
Many thanks.