# reshaping dataframe in R?

Tags: r, reshape2

this is my dataframe action_slippers:

```
                   X_id                       cd      iios                       ui     w
1  56548c6ab65dd425cc3dda13 2015-11-24T16:12:26.572Z 194635691 563734c3b65dd40e340eaa56 0.010
2  56548df4b84c321fe4cdfb91 2015-11-24T16:19:00.798Z 194153563 56548df4b84c321fe4cdfb8f 0.010
3  56548fc7735e782a88591662 2015-11-24T16:26:46.952Z 177382028 563e12657d4c410c5832579c 0.010
4  565494e1b84c321fe4ce2f44 2015-11-24T16:48:33.828Z 177382031 563e12657d4c410c5832579c 0.010
5  5654994a735e782a88595802 2015-11-24T17:07:18.269Z 195129144 56549946735e782a885957e6 0.080
6  56549ce2b65dd425cc3e550c 2015-11-24T17:22:42.775Z 196972549 565181854c24b410e4891e11 0.010
7  56549f9bb84c321fe4ce7a3a 2015-11-24T17:34:19.732Z 194153563 56549f9bb84c321fe4ce7a37 0.010
8  5654a35a735e782a8859a055 2015-11-24T17:50:18.068Z 196258704 5654a35a735e782a8859a053 0.010
9  5654a5bab8e3a9227cffd593 2015-11-24T18:00:26.102Z 194907960 56320e0e55e89c3e14e26d3d 0.010
10 5654a7bb735e782a8859c495 2015-11-24T18:08:59.476Z 196950156 5651b53fec231f1df8482d23 0.027
11 5654a8955ff32d03cc2124b3 2015-11-24T18:12:37.381Z 194907960 5654a8955ff32d03cc2124b1 0.080
```

ı wrote following codes:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(actions_slippers)) {

if (actions_slippers$w[i]==0.027) {
  user_id=actions_slippers$ui[i]

  for (j in 1:i) {
    mydf <- data.frame(
      ui = c(actions_slippers$ui[1:i]),
      w = c(actions_slippers$w[1:i]),
      iios = factor(
        c(actions_slippers$iios[1:i]),
        levels = unique(x)))

  a=  dcast(mydf, formula = ui ~ iios, 
          fill = 0, value.var = "w", 
          fun.aggregate = sum, drop = FALSE)
```

I used the reshape2 package and action_slippers dataframe transformed to a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  ui 194635691 194153563 177382028 177382031 195129144 196972549 196258704 194907960 196950156 194139014 153444738 192982501 192891196
1 237      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.01     0.000         0         0         0         0
2 261      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0         0         0
3 290      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0         0         0
4 483      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0         0         0
5 485      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.027         0         0         0         0
6 533      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0         0         0
7 534      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.08      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0         0         0
8 535      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000         0         0         0         0
9 536      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.00     0.000         0         0         0         0
```

but the problem is ui values are changed  as you can see.
Can anyone one tell me How can I prevent to changing values of ui?

Comment: seems to be a "stringsAsFactors" problem you ran into ... 
try setting stringsAsFactors to "FALSE"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have converted the factor `actions_slippers$ui` into a number. To avoid this, you can convert it into a character, by converting:

```
ui = c(actions_slippers$ui[1:i])
```

to

```
ui = c(as.character(actions_slippers$ui[1:i]))
```

However, your code is unnecessarily complex - it's always a good idea to avoid for loops in r if possible. Looking at your code, you want to exclude everything after the last `w == 0.027`, add the `w` column for each combination of `iios` and `ui` and spread the result.

Here's a much quicker solution, using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
actions_slippers %>%
   filter(row_number() <= which.max(w == 0.027)) %>%
   group_by(iios, ui) %>%
   summarise(w = sum(w)) %>%
   spread(iios, w, fill = 0)

Source: local data frame [9 x 10]
                        ui 177382028 177382031 194153563 194635691 194907960 195129144 196258704 196950156
                    (fctr)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)
1 56320e0e55e89c3e14e26d3d      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00     0.000
2 563734c3b65dd40e340eaa56      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000
3 563e12657d4c410c5832579c      0.01      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000
4 565181854c24b410e4891e11      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000
5 5651b53fec231f1df8482d23      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.027
6 56548df4b84c321fe4cdfb8f      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000
7 56549946735e782a885957e6      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.08      0.00     0.000
8 56549f9bb84c321fe4ce7a37      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.000
9 5654a35a735e782a8859a053      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.01     0.000
Variables not shown: 196972549 (dbl)
```

Comment: @ jeremycg, thanks. I converted it into a character and its worked for me.ı want to use dplyr package but never used before.here is a link that my main purpose int this issue.If u have tıme to check would be great for me.Many thanks in advance.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34407923/how-to-build-a-cosine-similarity-function-in-r